# How can I be sure a new laptop will run Windows 7?

Tags: windows

I'm looking at buying a new laptop. I run Debian Linux as my primary operating system; however, I would like the option of booting up Windows 7 once in a while.

How can I be totally sure a machine will run Windows 7? I will have absolutely *no* opportunity to return it if it doesn't; I'll have to get it right the first time.

Please, no comments about how Windows 7 is end of life, is not maintained, is not protected against the latest security exploits, is not the latest and greatest, or that anything it can do can be done in the current version as well.

I trust Windows 7 (sort of) and will *not* move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should basically look for something with a bit of an older CPU.

This is from the official [**Windows Processor Requirements**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements) page from Microsoft:

> ***Intel Processors***
>                                                                                                                                                                                           Up through the following 6th Generation Intel Processors (Intel Core
>   i3/i5/i7-6xxx, Core m3/m5/m7-6xxx, and Xeon E3-xxxx v5), and through
>   series equivalent Intel Atom, Celeron and Pentium Processors
>
> ***AMD Processors***
>           Up through the following AMD 6th Generation Processors (A-Series Ax-8xxx & E-Series Ex-8xxx & FX-870K)